# Remove duplicate bigram and and add it's sum to orignal count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp, tfidfvectorizer

I have created bigrams dataframe like this

[image: on]

In this there are bigrams with reversed words, I want to remove the bigrams with reversed word(e.g. remove "good network" ) but add up their "sum" or  else  maybe reverse the bigram words so that the identical bigrams "sum" can be added together and remove the duplicate bigram afterewards

Desired Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create the sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'terms': ['network good', 'good network', 'net speed', 'good rate', 'rate good'],
    'sum': [1, 3, 6, 7, 70]
})

# split the strings in `term` column by space, sort the resulting list and 
# join again. This will help to order the jumbled bigrams

df['terms'] = df['terms'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(sorted(x.split(' '))))

# Do the groupby and sum the `sum` column
df = df.groupby('terms').sum().reset_index()
```

### Input dataframe

```
          terms  sum
0  network good    1
1  good network    3
2     net speed    6
3     good rate    7
4     rate good   70
```

### Output dataframe

```
          terms  sum
0  good network    4
1     good rate   77
2     net speed    6
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Also just curious does sorted() sorts the bigrams list  into alphabetical order ?

Comment: Yes, [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) sorts the input list and returns a new sorted list.