# Sorting the order of bigrams, removing duplicates and summing up its frequencies

Tags: pandas, sorting, text-mining, counting, n-gram

I have a dataframe which has columns `bigrams` and `counts`. The dataframe looks like:

| bigrams | counts |
| --- | --- |
| ('asset', 'experience') | 1 |
| ('qualifications', 'your') | 1 |
| ('your', 'contribution') | 1 |
| ('contribution', 'bilingual') | 1 |
| ('your', 'qualifications') | 1 |
| ('bilingual', 'contribution') | 1 |

So, for `('contribution', 'bilingual')`it should sort the bigrams in alphabetical order and output `('bilingual', 'contribution')` in the `bigrams` column, remove one of the duplicates, and the counts should add to 2 in the `counts` column. This process should happen for all such occurances of `('contribution', 'bilingual')` and for all such bigrams (like, for example here in the above dataframe, `('your', 'contribution')`) throughout the dataframe. Then, finally the bigrams which has the maximum frequency should be at the top of the `counts` column, followed by the bigrams in decreasing order of their frequencies.

I also want to preserve the format in which the bigrams are there in the above dataframe.

I want my output to be like this:

| bigrams | counts |
| --- | --- |
| ('qualifications', 'your') | 2 |
| ('bilingual', 'contribution') | 2 |
| ('your', 'contribution') | 1 |
| ('asset', 'experience') | 1 |

I tried to solve this based on these two SO questions [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61652075/remove-duplicate-bigram-and-and-add-its-sum-to-orignal-count) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69926265/sum-duplicate-bigrams-in-dataframe), but they are giving me weird answers, not what I need.

The code with which I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('emplois_df_FonctionsStagiaire_bigrams_counts.csv')

# splitting the strings in `bigrams` column by space, sort the resulting list and join again. This will help to order the jumbled bigrams
#df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['bigrams', 'counts']
df['bigrams'] = df['bigrams'].apply(lambda x: ' ' .join(sorted(x.strip().split(', '))))
#OR
df['bigrams'] = df['bigrams'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x.strip('()').split(', '))))
# Do the groupby and sum the `sum` column
df_new = df.groupby('bigrams', as_index=False)['counts'].sum()

df_new.to_csv('emplois_df_FonctionsStagiaire_bigrams_sorted_counts.csv', index= False)
```

`type(df.bigrams.values[1])` gives `<class 'str'>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

# apply ast.literal_eval if necessary:
df['bigrams'] = df['bigrams'].apply(literal_eval)

df['bigrams'] = df['bigrams'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)))
df = df.groupby('bigrams').agg({'counts':'sum'}).reset_index()

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                     bigrams  counts
0        (asset, experience)       1
1  (bilingual, contribution)       2
2       (contribution, your)       1
3     (qualifications, your)       2
```